# Snapsvg - get height and width of text element

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I am altering the  elements contents using

```
svgTextLines[name].node.innerHTML = line.val();
svgTextLines[name].node.textContent = line.val();
```

and trying to get the height and width of the element after the content has changed but I cant seem to find any property in the elemement.node object that gets updated. As the element has not transformed I can understand why but is there a way I can get this information?

Regards

Comment: getBBox is the way to go.

Comment: getBBox will only return the bounding box of a transformed element wont it? its not transformed.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. If you explain with examples what you want and why getBBox does not give you the values you want that would be helpful.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm doing this but I'm getting zeros in all even though it was added to the DOM and it has text.

Comment: @kuhaku I suggest you ask your own question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/) and I had the same problem.
You can use [getBoundingClientRect](http://caniuse.com/#search=getBoundingClientRect) to get an object with this parameter.

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
Snap.load("mascot.svg", function (f) {
  s.append(f);
  var rect = s.searchAll("g")[0];
  var dimens = rect.node.getBoundingClientRect();     
  console.log(dimens.width)
});
```